# R : convert character date "Dec 31, 2016 07:29 PM" to 31/12/2016 19:29:00

Tags: r, date, character

I want to convert character date in format "Dec 31, 2016 07:29 PM" to 31/12/2016 19:29:00 in R.

"demon" is the data frame and 7 is the date column number.
I have tried: 
`as.Date(demon[, 7])` this results in

> "Error in charToDate(x) :    character string is not in a standard
>   unambiguous format"

`as.Date(demon[, 7], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` results in

> NA's being generated.

Comment: Try `as.Date(x, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p")`. Then use `format.Date` to convert to your final format.

Comment: `as.Date` will drop the time portion of the date/time object.  You can use `as.POSIXct(x, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p")` to convert the string into a date/time object.

Comment: `format(lubridate::mdy_hm("Dec 31, 2016 07:29 PM"), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: `format(strptime(x,"%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p"), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`